# Rails decimal field is not saving correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql

I have a `price: decimal` field on my model and when I say model.price = 10, I am expecting it to be 20.0 but what it saves is `0.02e2`. Any idea what is happening?

Migration has this: `t.decimal :price`
and this is what I do in the rails console:

```sh
irb(main):019:0> app.price
=> 0.2e2
irb(main):020:0> app.price = 2000
=> 2000
irb(main):021:0> app.save!
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  MyModel Update (0.5ms)  UPDATE "my_model" SET "price" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "my_models"."id" = $3  [["price", "2000.0"], ["updated_at", "2021-02-10 08:28:50.075958"], ["id", "44e7448f-0504-49cb-be76-55627fe57f1e"]]
   (33.0ms)  COMMIT
=> true
irb(main):022:0> app.price
=> 0.2e4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `e` here stands for exponent (although some people may more commonly know it as *power*).

As it's a *decimal* column, we're working in tens.

10<sup>2</sup> = 100

0.2 x 100 = 20.

So it *is* storing 20. It's just not immediately obvious if you're unfamiliar with this kind of thing.

The object being returned is a `BigDecimal`. In a Rails Console, you can prove it:

```
BigDecimal("20")
=> 0.2e2
BigDecimal("20").to_f
=> 20.0
BigDecimal("20").to_i
=> 20
```

Comment: Well, yeah, at least basic math is necessary for programming :)